# fopen/fread vs file_get_contents for reading files prior to storing in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, fopen, file-get-contents

I'm writing a PHP script which allows a user to upload a file via a form.  The file will be stored in a MEDIUMBLOB field of a table in a MySQL database.

To do this, the content of the uploaded file needs to be read, then inserted.  Fairly trivial stuff, but I'm hoping to get some thoughts about which of the following methods is best/most reliable when dealing with files that are not just text files.

```
$file_data = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

versus...

```
$file_pointer = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$file_data = fread($file_pointer, filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])); //or use $_FILES['file']['size'] instead of filesize()
```

Both file_get_contents and fopen/fread are "binary safe", while fopen allows me to open the file in binary mode...  I'm wondering if that will make a difference.

Lastly, most scripts will sanitise the file data before inserting - many use addslashes, but I would use the mysqli's "real_escape_string" method...

However, I notice that none of the examples I've viewed strip the escape characters when retrieving the data (e.g. the download script retrieves the data from the database, sends headers then just echoes the data without any kind of stripslashes...)

Is this a problem, or am I missing something?

Cheers,
Greg

Comment: file system for files, its in the name.

Comment: Neither of these answer the questions asked.  I did not ask whether it was better to store files in the database or the file system.  I'm well aware that the file system is usually a much better option.  I am required to demonstrate storing things in the database and wanted to ensure I was doing so in the best/most efficient manner.